# Enthusiastically Russianify a String

Tags: code-golf, string

Many of you may have interacted with people from Russia on the internet at some point, and a subset of you may have noticed the slightly odd method they have of expressing themselves.

e.g. `удали игру нуб)))`

where the `)))` are added for emphasis on the previous statement, I have been working on a theory that the ratio of `)`'s to the rest of the string is directly proportional to the amount of implied emphasis, however I oftentimes find it difficult to compute the ratio on the fly, as I am also trying to cope with a slew of abuse, so I would like the shortest possible code to help me calculate what the resulting string should be, for a value of enthusiasm between 0 and 500%, given the original, unenthusiastic string, this will aid my research greatly as I will not have to type out bulky scripts every time I wish to test my hypothesis.

So, the challenge:

write a full program or function, which, provided two arguments, a string of unknown length, and a number, in either integer format (between 0 and 500) or in decimal format (between 0 and 5, with 2 points of accuracy) will

- return/display the original string, suffixed with a number of `)`'s
- the number will be the calculated as a ratio of the input number to the string length.
- so if the number 200, or 2.00 was provided, 200% of the string must be suffixed as `)`'s
- the number of brackets rounded to in decimal situations does not matter.
- script is required to support Printable ASCII characters.
- only has to support one input number format, of your choice.

Examples:

```
"codegolf" 125      = codegolf))))))))))
"codegolf" 75       = codegolf))))))
"noob team omg" 0.5 = noob team omg))))))
"hi!" 4.99          = hi!)))))))))))))))
```

Example code (PowerShell) (with decimal input):

```
Function Get-RussianString ([string]$InputStr,[decimal]$Ratio){
    $StrLen = $InputStr.Length
    $SuffixCount = $StrLen * $Ratio
    $Suffix = [string]::New(")",$SuffixCount)
    return $InputStr + $Suffix
}

Get-RussianString "codegolf" 0.5
codegolf))))
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

Comment: "the number of brackets rounded to in decimal situations does not matter" -- Does this mean the 4th test-case could also print 14 brackets instead of 15?

Comment: @smls yes, either the floor or ceiling of any decimal is acceptable.

Comment: I get a variation of two `)`s for the `hi!,4.99` example. `")"*(LEN(S$)*N)` produces 14 `)`s, `")"*LEN(S$)*N` and `")"*LEN(S$*N)` give 12.

Comment: I'm confused, do Russians really use `)` for emphasis like an `!`? Is it some encoding issue?

Comment: @CaptainMan I believe it's more like smiley faces than `!`s, but they do type them as is, it's not super common, but it's quite iconic.

Comment: @CaptainMan No `)` is reduced emoticon `:)`. It is used very common between young people as far as I know.

Comment: `)` is not an emphasis, it is simply the smiley. As far as I know, it is harder to type `:` when using Russian keyboard layout, therefore they smile without eyes.

Comment: @Juris it's as hard to write `:` on Russian layout (ЙЦУКЕН) as it is to type `^` on QWERTY. But indeed, the `)` is a reduced version of `:)`. It's much easier to press and hold Shift-0 than to repeatedly alternate keys.

Comment: I think the appropriate word for _"to make something Russian"_ is to Russify it, or Russianize it (I prefer the former).

Comment: Will you ever get `500` or `5.0` as input?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm intrigued as to how it would make a difference to your code, but yes the range is inclusive for this challenge, primarily because I want the 0 case to be handled.

Comment: @ConnorLSW I did not just ask for my code, but for everybody's reference BTW.

Comment: Just by the way, the example should be `удали игру нуб)))` (instead of `деинсталляция игра нуб)))`).

Comment: Do you require the program to both accept the decimal and integer formats? I read the challenge that way, but your example only accepts decimals.

Comment: @Justin the example code is decimal only, but the input type is your own decision, only one is required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ȮL×Ċ”)x
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39inc/h6Ue6HjXM1az4//9/RqbifxM9S0sA)**

Uses the decimal format.

#### How?

```
ȮL×Ċ”)x - Main link: string, decimal
Ȯ       - print string
 L      - length(string)
  ×     - multiply by the decimal
   Ċ    - ceiling (since rounding method is flexible)
    ”)  - a ')' character
      x - repeated that many times
        - implicit print
```

Comment: @ConnorLSW I just noticed that this will print the required string as a full program, but that the specification states "return" - is this OK?

Comment: any [standard accepted output format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) is fine

Comment: no worries - this is my first challenge so there's a few of these things that I missed, i've updated it in the question to be more clear - thanks for asking.

Answer (score 17):

## Perl 6, 21 bytes

```perl6
{$^a~")"x$^b*$a.comb}
```

Answer (score 16):

### Common Lisp, <del>59</del> <del>52</del> 50

Parentheses? I am in.

```
(lambda(s n)(format()"~a~v@{)~}"s(*(length s)n)0))
```

#### Details

```
(lambda(s n)               ; two arguments (string and ratio)
  (format ()               ; format as string
          "~a~v@{)~}"      ; control string (see below)
          s                ; first argument (string)
          (* (length s) n) ; second argument (number of parens)
          0))              ; one more element, the value does not matter
```

#### Format control  string

- `~a` : pretty print argument (here the given string)
- `~v@{...~}` : iteration block, limited to V iteration, where V is taken as an argument, namely the `(* ...)` expression. The iteration is supposed to iterate over a list, but when you add the `@` modifier, the list is the remaining list of arguments to the format function. There must be at least one element in the iterated list (otherwise we exit, disregarding V). That is why there is an additional argument to format (0).

Since no element in the list is consumed by the format, the loop is infinite but fortunately, it is also bounded by V, a.k.a. the number of parentheses to be printed.

---

Edit: thanks to Michael Vehrs for pointing out that there is no need to round the numerical argument (the question allows to truncate/round however we want, so the default behavior works here).

Comment: (())/10 not enough parentheses

Comment: Who thought this language is a good idea?

Comment: Scheme's `format` accepts a decimal argument to `v`. Maybe Common Lisp's does, too?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Indeed, thanks a lot.

Comment: @coredump Actually, I should have said "Guile's `format` accepts ...", since standard Scheme `format` does not support `~r`; and Guile's `format` follows the example of Common Lisp's.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>38</strike> <strike>31</strike> 30 bytes

```
s=>n=>s+')'.repeat(s.length*n)
```

```js
f=s=>n=>s+')'.repeat(s.length*n)

console.log(f("hi!")(4.99))
```

Comment: Nice, I think that's the shortest possible. You can save a byte through currying: `s=>n=>s+')'.repeat(s.length*n)` (it would then be called like `f("hi!")(4.99)`)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda s,p:s+len(s)*p/100*')'
```

**s** in the string, **p** is the percentage (integer).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VcxBDoIwEEDRtZ5iXE0HJ7EYiYGEm7gp0mKTttNQ7l8VV27fT76DER41mDjNBgrnoZyDTapQky@t1g0SVifrN4FPoPAps10kOOT22hH/yf0HSWSCzZoIEhdk6PTOL39CvvU9DcdDXn3awKnPluob)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
g*ï')×¹ì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5@udXi9uubh6Yd2Hl7z/39yfkpqen5OGpeJngEA)

```
g*       # Length, multiplied by emphasis.
  ï')×   # Covnerted to an integer, push that many parenthesis.
      ¹ì # Prepend original string.
```

Works for both integer and decimal, arguments order: `f(String, Double)`

Comment: [-1 in the new version of 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/XUtd8/D0QzsPr/n/Pzk/JTU9PyeNy0TPAAA), where the `ï` is done implicitly for `×` with float argument.

Comment: And here’s a 7-byter that works on both legacy and modern 05AB1E: [sg*F')«](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/OF3LTV3z0Or//w31jEy5kvNTUtPzc9IA).

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 30 bytes

```py
lambda s,r:s+')'*int(len(s)*r)
```

Uses the decimal input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqFCsU2RVrK2uqa6VmVeikZOap1GsqVWk@b@gCMRP01BKzk9JTc/PSVPSUTDUMzLV1OTCJmWgZ44ilZefn6RQkpqYq5Cfmw6WR5HOyFQECproWVpqav4HAA)

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
*\)s*lpz
```

[Online Test!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a%5C%29s%2alpz&input=0.5%0Anoob+team+omg&debug=0) Takes the excitement ratio first, then the string to be enthused about.

Explanation:

```
      pz  print out the enthused string
     l    ... and get its length
    *...Q multiply that by the ratio
   s      floor to get an integer, let's call this S
 \)       single-character string ")"
* ")" S   multiply that integer by the string, which gives a string of )s of length S.
          implicitly print that string of S )s.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 33 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args;$a+')'*($b*$a.Length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@SqKOSZKuSWJRebK2SqK2uqa6loZKkpZKo55Oal16Sofn///@MTMX/JnqWlgA)

Supports decimal format.

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>62</s> <s>46</s> 42 bytes

Anonymous function that takes string `a` and decimal `n`, prints output to stdout.

```
pryr::f(cat(a,rep(")",n*nchar(a)),sep=""))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
*s*lpzE")
```

Takes two lines of input: string and ratio (decimal).

[Try it on pyth.herokuapp.com](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2as%2alpzE%22%29&input=%22hi%22%0A1.5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=codegolf%0A1.25%0Acodegolf%0A0.75%0Anoob+team+omg%0A0.5%0Ahi%21%0A4.99&debug=1&input_size=2)

#### Explanation

`A` denotes a function's first argument, `B` its second argument.

```
*s*lpzE")
    pz     # print the input string
   lAA     # take the length of the printed string
      E    # read the next line of input (the emphasis ratio)
  *AAAB    # multiply the length by the ratio
 sAAAAA    # floor the result
*AAAAAA")  # repeat ")" n times
           # implicit print
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 33 bytes

Takes decimal input.

```
Prompt Str1,A
")
For(I,0,9
Ans+Ans
End
Str1+sub(Ans,1,AI
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 29 bytes

```perl
sub{($_=pop).')'x(y///c*pop)}
```

(Number is first arg, string is second.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Ky1OVSguKcpMLrHmKgWyyxOL8jLz0outubhyKxVU0hRs/xeXJlVrqMTbFuQXaOqpa6pXaFTq6@sna4H4tf@BCguKMvNKgGp17TQM9YxMdRTUDY2MTdQ1dRSUYvKUrP8DAA)

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
l_,ld*')*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@58Tr5OToqWuqfX/f0BRfnpRYm5uZl66QkBpVVVOarFCYl6KgnN@SqqCe35OGpehnpEpAA)

Input string on the first line, emphasis ratio in range 0 to 5 on the second.

#### Explanation

```
l    e# Read input string.
_,   e# Duplicate, get length.
ld   e# Read emphasis ratio.
*    e# Multiply by length.
')*  e# Get that many parentheses.
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
yn*:"41h
```

This solution uses the decimal form of the second input

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@Zp2WlZGKY8f@/enJ@Smp6fk6aOpehnpEpAA)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab first input as a string
        % Implicitly grab the second input as a number
y       % Make a copy of the first input
n       % Compute the length of the string
*       % Multiply the decimal by the length to determine the # of )'s (N)
:       % Create the array [1...N]
"       % For each element in this array
  41    % Push 41 to the stack (ACSII for ")")
  h     % Horizontally concatenate this with the current string
        % Implicit end of for loop and display
```

Answer (score 3):

## sB~, 17 bytes

```
i\,N?\;')'*(N*l(\
```

Explained:

```
i\,N    input a string and a number
?\;     print the string
')'*    also print ) multiplied by...
(N*l(\  the number times the string length.
```

Parentheses are closed automatically

Here's the output of the compiler, if you're interested:

```
 INPUT  S$ ,N? S$ ;")"*(N* LEN(  S$ ))
```

This version of the compiler was written on 1/27/2017 at 11:12 pm, which might have been a few minutes after this question was posted.
So here's a version which works on the oldest version of the compiler, written an hour earlier: `iS$,N?S$;')'*(N*l(S$))` (22 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

## PostgreSQL, 102 bytes

```
create function q(text,int)returns text as $$select rpad($1,(100+$2)*length($1)/100,')')$$language sql
```

#### Details

Uses the integer input format.

This simply right-pads the input string with parens out to the target length.

```
create function q(text,int)
returns text as $$
    select rpad($1,             -- Pad the string input
        (100 + $2) *            -- to 100 + int input % ...
        length($1) / 100,       -- ...of the input string
        ')')                    -- with ) characters
$$ language sql
```

Called with

```
select q('codegolf', 125), q('codegolf', 75);
select q('noob team omg', 50), q('hi!', 499);
```

Answer (score 2):

### [C# Interactive,](http://csharppad.com/gist/67f46912a600cfecf2e99e537cdc913d) <s>77</s> 67 bytes

```
string r(string s,int p)=>s+new string(')',(int)(s.Length*p/100d));
```

C# interactive is sweet.

Comment: If you are using C# Interactive that needs to be in the header otherwise, in C#, you should include the `using System;` or fully qualify `Math`. Also, not sure if you can do it in interactive, but you could compile to a `Func<string, Func<int, string>>` to save bytes i.e. `s=>p=>s+new...`

Comment: Also you probably don't need the call to `Math.Round` just casting to an `int` should call `Floor` and the OP said either `Floor` or `Ceiling` is fine

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 45 bytes

```bash
echo $1`seq -s\) $[${#1}*$2/100+1]|tr -cd \)`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoGKYUJxaqKBbHKOpoBKtUq1sWKulYqRvaGCgbRhbU1KkoJucohCjmfD////k/JTU9PyctP/mpgA)

Integer input.

Comment: `echo $1\`jot -b \) -s '' $[${#1}*$2/100]\`` 40 bytes :) [try it out](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BxTAhK79EQTdJIUZTQbdYQV1dQSVapVrZsFZLxUjf0MAgNuH///9l@SnZiSX5eZnJ/00NAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 27 bytes

Straightforward solution

```
{s,r->s+')'*(s.length()*r)}
```

Test program :

```
def f = {s,r->s+')'*(s.length()*r)}

println f("hi!", 4.99)
println f("noob team omg", 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol, 39 bytes

```
func[a b][append/dup a")"b * length? a]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 40 bytes

Quite boring solution :

```
#(reduce str %(repeat(*(count %)%2)")"))
```

Just reduces `str` function on a list of closing parentheses with a string as initial parameter.

See it online : https://ideone.com/5jEgWS

Not-so-boring solution (64 bytes) :

```
#(.replace(str(nth(iterate list(symbol %))(*(count %)%2)))"(""")
```

Converts input string to a symbol (to get rid of quotes) and repeatedly applies function `list` on it generating infinite sequence like this: `(a (a) ((a)) (((a))) ... )`. Takes `nth` element converts it to string and replaces all opening parentheses with nothing.

See it online : https://ideone.com/C8JmaU

Comment: `#(.replaceAll(str(nth(iterate list %)(*(count %)%2)))"[(\"]""")`
1 byte less (yay). I wanted to do comp but can't get it below 70 bytes.

Comment: You can change `")"` to `\)` to save a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## SimpleTemplate, 92 bytes

Takes the string as the first parameter and the "ratio" as the second.
The ratio is between 0 and 5, with 2 decimal places.

```
{@echoargv.0}{@callstrlen intoL argv.0}{@set*Y argv.1,L}{@callstr_repeat intoO")",Y}{@echoO}
```

As you can see, it is non-optimal.
The 2 `{echo}` there could be reduced to 1.
Due to a bug in the compiler, this code can't be reduced much further.

---

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@echo argv.0}
{@call strlen into length argv.0}
{@set* ratio argv.1, length}
{@call str_repeat into parenthesis ")", ratio}
{@echo parenthesis}
```

---

If no bug existed, the code would look like this, 86 bytes:

```
{@callstrlen intoL argv.0}{@set*Y argv.1,L}{@callstr_repeat intoO")",Y}{@echoargv.0,O}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 24 bytes

A reimplementation of the old answer into the new specification. Input is as a positive integer first, then the string.

```
ɪ{100}viħɖf0ɑ")"x1esøɒʕo
```

Explanation:

```
ɪ{100}viħɖf0ɑ")"x1esøɒʕo
ɪ                        (push input int)
 {100}                   (push 100)
      v                  (divide int//100)
       iħ                (push input str, push len)
         ɖ               (rotate top 3 clockwise)
          f              (multiply int//100 * len)
           0             (push 0)
            ɑ            (begin loop, from 0 to int//100 * len)
             ")"         (push ")")
                x        (concat)
                 1esø    (increment index)
                     ɒ   (end loop)
                      ʕ  (list to str)
                       o (print)
```

---

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 18 bytes (WIP language) (OLD)

I discovered some bugs in my interpreter because of this challenge. Takes input as `string` then `integer`.

```
iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo
```

No TIO interpreter yet, but is runnable by cloning the repository above, and calling `python3 main.py "code here"`.

```
iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo
i                  ; push string input
 ɢ                 ; peek, push string length
  291tʃ            ; push (1 + 9)^2
       ɪ           ; push number input
        ðθ         ; push [num / 100 * len]
          œ        ; start loop: pop, run ceil(n) times
           <)>     ; push string ")"
              ɲ    ; swap top 2 elements of the stack
               q   ; pop, pop, push concatenated strings
                ɶ  ; end loop
                 o ; output
```

Sample cases:

```
python3 main.py "iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo"
codegolf
125
codegolf))))))))))

python3 main.py "iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo"
iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo
300
iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

python3 main.py "iɢ291tʃɪðθœ<)>ɲqɶo"
less than 1.00
50
less than 1.00)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é┴eó¡µf
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82c165a2ade666&i=%22codegolf%22+1.25%0A%22codegolf%22+0.75%0A%22noob+team+omg%22+0.5%0A%22hi%21%22+4.99&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

### SmileBASIC, 29 bytes

```
INPUT S$,N?S$;")"*(LEN(S$)*N)
```

Comment: since `3*4.99` = `14.97`, only `14` or `15` would be acceptable as answers, the 29 bytes version should work fine though, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki) (Golfish), 17 bytes

```
i:a=?v
R*Il~/Hr)`
```

[Try it here](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=i%3Aa%3D%3Fv%0AR%2aIl%7e%2FHr%29%60&input=hi%21%0A4.99).

The top line reads characters (`i`) until it finds a newline (ASCII 10, `a`), then goes down (`v`).

Then we discard one character (the newline) with `~`, push the length of the stack (`l`), read a float (`I`), multiply the two, and repeatedly (`R`) push the character ")" that many times. Finally, reverse the stack (`r`), output it and halt (`H`).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```php
<?=str_pad($s=$argv[1],strlen($s)*++$argv[2],")");
```

takes string and decimal number as command line arguments; cuts padding. Run with `-r`;

**breakdown**

```php
<?=                     // print ...
str_pad(                    // pad
    $s=$argv[1],            // string=argument 1
    strlen($s)*++$argv[2],  // to string length*(1+argument 2) 
    ")"                     // using ")" as padding string
);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
#<>Table[")",#2Tr[1^#]]&
```

Unnamed function taking a list of characters and a decimal number as input and returning a string. `Tr[1^#]` is a sneaky golfy way to calculate the length of a list, so `#2Tr[1^#]` computes the required number of parentheses. `Table[")",...]` produces a list of that many right parentheses (all decimals automatically rounded down, which is nice). Finally, `#<>` concatenates the input string to the parentheses, flattening the list produced by `Table` as it goes.

Comment: That's quite cheaty, taking the string as a list of characters, but returning as a multi-character string. For consistent IO formats you could replace `<>` with `~Join~` at a cost of 4 bytes

Comment: I'd be interested in a community judgment on this issue. If it's cheat**ing**, then of course I'll avoid this type of mismatch. But if it's just cheat**y** - well, it seems to me that cheaty is very much on topic for this site :)

Comment: The challenge specification is sufficiently vague: `return/display the original string, suffixed with a number of )'s` (though I'd be picky with **original** string). Many other challenges specifically state "I/O formats must be consistent". If it's not a default rule, I guess you're in the white-enough part of the gray area.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP community consensus applies for I/O methods, so I believe this is valid Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

```
->(s,n){s+')'*(s.size*n)}
```

I'm using **lambdas**. The test program would be something like:

```
f=->(s,n){s+')'*(s.size*n)}
f.("codegolf", 1.5)        # => "codegolf))))))))))))"
f.("hi!", 4.99)            # => "hi!))))))))))))))"
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU AWK, 59 bytes

```
{t=sprintf("%"n*length(s)"s","");gsub(/ /,")",t);print s t}
```

Accepts arguments on command line (using the decimal form) like so:

```
: | awk -v s="codegolf" -v n=0.75 -f russianify.awk
```

Yes, AWK requires *something* to be attached to stdin, even if that something is 0 bytes returned by the no-op shell builtin. You could also use `echo | awk ...`, or really *anything* that doesn't contain a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 68 bytes

An anonymous function that accepts decimal input.

```
(fn [s n] (print (str s (reduce str (repeat (* n (count s)) ")")))))
```

Literally the first Lisp program I've ever written! I'm already having fun.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Lisp! :P In Clojure, you can use the condensed form of anonymous functions `#(...)`, and you can get rid of the `print` (since function returns should be acceptable). You can change `reduce` to `apply` for the `str` function, and you can change `")"` to `\)`, which does the same thing. So, the final code should be: `#(str %(apply str(repeat(*(count %)%2)\)))))`.

Comment: Also, the current state of your code doesn't work, `(#(...) "codegolf" 125)` must add 125 *percent* of the length of "codegolf" instead of 125 *times* the length of "codegolf". So, the fixed program would be: `#(str %(apply str(repeat(*(count %)%2 1/100)\))))`, which is 49 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 43 bytes

As unnamed lambda modifying its input, assuming `s` is similar to `std::string` (has `.append(int,char)` and assuming `p` to be of floating point type:

```cpp
[](auto&s,auto p){s.append(s.size()*p,41);}
```

Usage:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

auto f=
[](auto&s,auto p){s.append(s.size()*p,41);}
;


int main() {
 std::string s = "abcdefghijk";
 f(s,0.75);
 std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
s!n=s++([1..div(n*length s)100]>>")")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#dcmxCoMwFAXQ3a@4CR1MBUmKUhz0R0oHbdIYMO@VJvT3UxwdXM8pSdCYmqZ@mLa14VfTdXPk84qkjNbPaZJKqhLnQBhhuQLw@QbKuEC@2DrP21tCwNz607sfi5gXZDdHcPT79/rwaxC7dsNQ/g) Usage: `"codegolf" ! 125`

---

A version that takes a decimal number: (41 bytes)

```hs
s!n=s++([1..n*toRational(length s)]>>")")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#dcqxCsIwFEbh3af4ExwaC8GKIh3ah@gqDtHGNJDcK@a@f0Q6dXA936lF0VDatrl11tJBeHISmVxqkqcgC4q5j6M22tTsImHAzDsA708kwR76ybMPnF4aCp09Xf7i0V63SMwPiHcZnMN6bIclql8@276vXw) Usage: `"codegolf" ! 1.25`

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 16 bytes

```
P
,$')
 *i
 #
EI
```

Takes input as decimal, then newline, then string.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@x/ApaOirsmloJXJpaDM5er5/7@hnpEpV3J@Smp6fk4aAA)

### Explanation

Let's start from the bottom.

```
I
```

A raw string read from STDIN.

```
#
I
```

The length of the string.

```
*i
#
I
```

Multiply it by a number read from STDIN (the number is read first, since `i` comes before `I` in the source).

```
$')
*i
#
I
```

Repeat the character `)` that many times, rounding down.

```
,$')
 *i
 #
EI
```

Append to the original string (the `,` looks for arguments from the south and east, and `E` tells the southward seeker to turn east, where it finds the `I`).

```
P
,$')
 *i
 #
EI
```

Print the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+')pUÊ*V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=KycpcFXKKlY&input=ImhpISIKNC45OQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
l×')×+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWwlQzMlOTcnKSVDMyU5NyUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWNvZGVnb2xmJTBBNC4wJmZsYWdzPWU=)

Takes the string, then the decimal.

##### Explanation

```python
l×')×+  '# Implicit input
l        # Length of string input
 ×       # Multiply by the number
  ')×   '# Multiply by ")"
         # (implicit floor)
     +   # Append to the input
         # Implicit output
```